# Configuring AutoMapper in Multiple Projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I currently have built an MVC solution which has a web project (controllers/views/scripts), services project (business layer, builds view models), and repositories project (data access layer).

I have used AutoMapper in my projects in the past and am trying to configure AutoMapper in this solution. Normally, I configure all of my maps in `MapperConfig.cs` which is called in `Global.asax.cs`.

My Problem is that the web project which is where I normally configure AutoMapper only has reference to the services project and the services project only has reference to the data project. So, when I go to configure my maps as I normally would, I am unable to define maps for the data project due to the web project not having a reference to the data project. I need a way to configure my data access layer maps without adding a reference for the data project to the web project.

The project dependency diagram would look like the following:

Web Proj --> Services Proj  --> Data Proj

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Why do you want to have only one config for auto mapper?
Do you really have classes / dtos that span all your layers?

Comment: I have no classes that span all of my layers. I haven't been able to find a way to define maps on a per project basis - that is what I'm trying to overcome. With Ninject, I did this by creating classes in each project that inherit from `NinjectModule`. If you can post an AutoMapper example, I will gladly accept

Comment: How about using a static constructor that would init the maps in each project - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136415/where-to-place-automapper-map-registration-in-referenced-dll

Comment: Or even this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458731/how-to-configure-auto-mapper-in-class-library-project

Comment: Hey, I've written an answer, please let me know if you need any help

Comment: @ironstone13 im working on a solution now. if it works for me, I'll gladly accept

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to have a *single* mapping registration file across all projects, especially that you say that you don't have any cross-cutting types.

The *simplest* way would be to define a configuration file **per project**, and have those configurations *call each other, repeating the layered dependencies of your assemblies*, like below:

```
Global.asax.cs --> WebProjMapRegistrations.Register()-->ServicesMapRegistrations.Register()-->DataMapRegistrations.Register()
```

Alternatively, you could use the [Assembly Scanning for auto configuration](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html?highlight=assembly%20scanning#assembly-scanning-for-auto-configuration)

As described by @Jimmy Bogard, when you run your web app, **all** assemblies of your application will eventually get loaded into your application domain - so you can get all the profiles from all the assemblies and add them to mapper config: [How to Initialize AutoMapper Profiles in referenced project DLLs in ASP.Net webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38555702/how-to-initialize-automapper-profiles-in-referenced-project-dlls-in-asp-net-weba)

Yet another alternative approach, that works for ASP.NET apps can be found here:
[Where to place AutoMapper map registration in referenced dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136415/where-to-place-automapper-map-registration-in-referenced-dll)

Comment: So, in my web project on startup do I scan my assemblies across the multiple projects and map registrations that exist in each of the projects, is that correct?

Comment: @CiaranGallagher using this method, you would call a method that registers your web project's maps from `global.asax.` and that method would register all maps needed in teh web project and also call a method which exists in the service layer called `ServicesMapRegistrations.Register()`. The service layer method would register all maps needed in the service layer as well as call `DataMapRegistrations.Register()` in the data project to register all maps in the data layer

Answer (score 1):

The way I've handled this in some ASP.Net MVC projects, is by using [AutoMapper Profiles](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration).

You create separate mapping Profiles that handle creating the Mappings for objects in that Project/Assembly.

You then add the profiles to the overall configuration manually, or you can use [Reflection/Assembly scanning](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#assembly-scanning-for-auto-configuration) to automatically load the profiles.